# WebLogic JDBC - Profile Harvest Frequency Seconds

Tags: cache, weblogic, jdbc

In the company I'm providing consulting services, when the database is updated by a process outside Weblogic Web Application, the updated data is not refreshed at once. Googling a bit I've found the following parameter in [JDBC configuration](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/pagehelp/JDBCjdbcdatasourcesjdbcdatasourceconfigconnectionpooltitle.html):

```
Profile Harvest Frequency Seconds

The number of seconds between when WebLogic Server harvests profile data.
When set to 0, harvesting of data is disabled.
MBean Attribute (Does not apply to application modules): 
JDBCConnectionPoolParamsBean.ProfileHarvestFrequencySeconds

Minimum value: 0
Maximum value: 2147483647
```

The default is set to 300.

Is this parameter that does the cache expiration? Or there's another configuration?

My idea is to expire the cache after 2 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This parameter sets how often JDBC  connection is profiled and the profile information logged to your logs. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/jdbc_admin/monitor.html

Are queries not returning the updated data? Could be a combination of the app, browser cache or another caching mechanism. If you can expand on the nature of the app and components involved, perhaps someone here could direct you in the right direction.

Comment: Possibly should be something related with the App JPA configuration. Thank you.